# An Example of sequence of R.V with $E(X_n) = X_0$ but $E(X_n^{1/2}) \to 0$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need an example of $\{X_n\}_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative, random variables, with the same finite expected value $E(X_n)=\mu_0$, that obeys:
$E(\sqrt{X_n})>E(\sqrt{X_{n+1}})>\dots \to 0$

Comment: Try to think about another example (which, I believe, is easier to construct). Namely, try to find a sequence $\{Y_n\}$ of positive random variables such that $E(Y_n)=1$ while $E(Y_n^2)$ increases to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

I think this satisfies the requirements:

$$X_n =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{n}\mu_0,  & \text{with probability $\dfrac{n-1}{n}$} \\[2ex]
\left(n-1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mu_0,  & \text{with probability $\dfrac{1}{n}$.}
\end{cases}$$

We have $E(X_n)=\mu_0$ and $E(\sqrt{X_n})=\sqrt{\mu_0}\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n^{3/2}} +\dfrac{\sqrt{n-1+1/n}}{n} \right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to do the trick. Now all I need to do is formulate it into my proof.

Comment: @JonesY Glad to help. :)